# What purpose is the ExtendedData element in Google Maps API V3?

Tags: xml, api, maps

When using the Google Maps API V3, it returns an element in the object called ExtendedData, and I'm not able to find out what purpose this serves.

```
  ["ExtendedData"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
    ["LatLonBox"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["north"]=>
        string(10) "36.0408578"
        ["south"]=>
        string(10) "36.0228111"
        ["east"]=>
        string(12) "-115.0831446"
        ["west"]=>
        string(12) "-115.1151594"
      }
    }
  }
```

The query sends a lat/long and this is part of the data returned. The rest of the data I can see the purpose, but have not been able to figure what the above is for. Perhaps it's because I'm not a map expert. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

LatLonBox are the coordinates of the location's bounding box.